# Symfony2 pass prototype parameter to container on load

Tags: symfony, service, prototype

well hello,
I want to create new bundle (a scroll bundle).I got it working.
But when i used to have a multiple scroller definition I got problems:

here is my app/config.yml

```
sifast_symash:
scrollers:
    scroller1:
        name: scroller1
        page_range: 5
        template:
            main_page: SifastTestBundle:Default:index.html.twig
            page: SifastTestBundle:Default:show.html.twig
    scroller2:
        name: scroller2
        page_range: 8
        template:
            main_page: SifastTestBundle:Default:index.html.twig
            page: SifastTestBundle:Default:show.html.twig
```

my bundle service.yml

```
parameters:
sifast_symash_scroller.class: Sifast\Bundle\SymashBundle\Manager\Scroll
    scroller : scroller1
services:
    sifast_symash_scroller:
        class : %sifast_symash_scroller.class%
        scope: prototype
        arguments:
            name: %sifast_symash_scroller.name%
            page_range: %sifast_symash_scroller.page_range%
            template:
                main_page : %sifast_symash_scroller.template.main_page%
                page : %sifast_symash_scroller.template.page%
```

the Configuration class :

```
   public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
{
    $builder = new TreeBuilder();

    $builder->root('sifast_symash')
        ->children()
            ->arrayNode('scrollers')
                ->prototype('array')
                    ->children()
                         ->scalarNode('name')->end()
                         ->integerNode('page_range')->defaultValue(5)->end()
                         ->arrayNode('template')
                            ->children()
                                ->scalarNode('main_page')->defaultValue("SifastTestBundle:Default:index.html.twig")->end()
                                ->scalarNode('page')->defaultValue("SifastTestBundle:Default:show.html.twig")->end()
                            ->end()
                         ->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ;
    return $builder;
}
```

SifastSymashExtension class

```
    $scroller = $config['scrollers'][$container->getParameter("scroller")];
    $container->setParameter('sifast_symash_scroller.name', $scroller['name']);
    $container->setParameter('sifast_symash_scroller.page_range', $scroller['page_range']);
    $container->setParameter('sifast_symash_scroller.template',$scroller['template']);
    $container->setParameter('sifast_symash_scroller.template.main_page',$scroller['template']['main_page']);
    $container->setParameter('sifast_symash_scroller.template.page',$scroller['template']['page']);
```

Now, in my controller, i want to select the scroller2 config, i want to set the parameter scroller, but i can't because container is already loaded:

```
    $this->container->setParameter("sifast_symash_scroller.scroller", "scroller1");
    $scroll = $this->get("sifast_symash_scroller");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Extension class you have to declare your scroller service definitions manually:

```
use Symfony\DependencyInjection\DependencyInjection\DefinitionDecorator;

// ...

public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    // ...

    $scrollers = $config['scrollers'];

    foreach ($scrollers as $name => $scroller) {
         // Inherit the definition of "sifast_symash.scroller".
         $definition = new DefinitionDecorator('sifast_symash.scroller');

         // Inject the configured values in the constructor of the class "Scroller".
         $definition->addArgument($scroller['name']);       // First argument
         $definition->addArgument($scroller['page_range']); // Second argument
         $definition->addArgument($scroller['template']);   // Third argument

         // Set a new definition suffixed with the configured name of the scroller.
         $container->setDefinition(
             sprintf('sifast_symash.scroller.%s', $name),
             $definition
         );
    }
}
```

Here is the corresponding `services.yml`:

```
parameters:
    sifast_symash.scroller.class: Sifast\Bundle\SymashBundle\Manager\Scroll

services:
    sifast_symash.scroller:
        class : %sifast_symash.scroller.class%
        abstract: true
```

**Note**

> I changed all "*sifast_symash_*" in "*sifast_symash.*" to follow Symfony2's recommandation.

Now you have a service for each of your scroller: `sifast_symash.scroller.scroller1` and `sifast_symash.scroller.scroller2` in your example.

You really should avoid the `scope: prototype` which is the antithesis of a service. Prefer a pattern provider (a service providing instances of a specific class) instead. Here is a [link](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack) showing where and why this pattern had been used in Symfony (for a unique instance here).

Comment: thank you! This resolved my problem. I even used a compiler pass for that.

Comment: Glad if I could help you! A compiler pass is a nice idea but remember that it is better to let that kind of code in your extension file if you do not need to access the definition of a service of another bundle (like tags)(because the scope of the container in the extension file is only the bundle itself). The main reason is that some compiler passes of another bundle can imply an order of execution with your code (this is bad because it imply an order for the bundles in your AppKernel). Letting your code in the extension file solves this by ensuring it to be executed before any compiler pass.

Comment: Just an example to understand! In your bundle you alter a definition of a service to add it a tag. Another bundle interpret the tag. If you do it in a compiler pass and the bundle interpreting the tag executes its compiler pass before your own, it won't take into account your service because this latter won't have the tag at that time. Hope I was clear..